# Case-insensitive comparison of sets in Python

Tags: python, django, compare

I have two sets (although I can do lists, or whatever):

```
a = frozenset(('Today','I','am','fine'))
b = frozenset(('hello','how','are','you','today'))
```

I want to get:

```
frozenset(['Today'])
```

or at least:

```
frozenset(['today'])
```

The second option is doable if I lowercase everything I presume, but I'm looking for a more elegant way.  Is it possible to do

```
a.intersection(b)
```

in a case-insensitive manner?

Shortcuts in Django are also fine since I'm using that framework.

Example from intersection method below (I couldn't figure out how to get this formatted in a comment):

```
print intersection('Today I am fine tomorrow'.split(),
                    'Hello How a re you TODAY and today and Today and Tomorrow'.split(),
                    key=str.lower)

[(['tomorrow'], ['Tomorrow']), (['Today'], ['TODAY', 'today', 'Today'])]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's version that works for any pair of iterables:

```
def intersection(iterableA, iterableB, key=lambda x: x):
    """Return the intersection of two iterables with respect to `key` function.

    """
    def unify(iterable):
        d = {}
        for item in iterable:
            d.setdefault(key(item), []).append(item)
        return d

    A, B = unify(iterableA), unify(iterableB)

    return [(A[k], B[k]) for k in A if k in B]
```

Example:

```
print intersection('Today I am fine'.split(),
                   'Hello How a re you TODAY'.split(),
                   key=str.lower)
# -> [(['Today'], ['TODAY'])]
```

Comment: Just to note, I get this error when doing this on unicode text:

*** TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

I'm looking to a solution now.

Comment: I would use `d=collections.defaultdict(list)` then `d[key(item)].append(item)`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: yes. `defaultdict` is well-suited for the job (I might have used Python 2.4 at work at the time).

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, even if you COULD "change on the fly" the comparison-related special methods of the sets' items (`__lt__` and friends -- actually, only `__eq__` needed the way sets are currently implemented, but that's an implementatio detail) -- and you can't, because they belong to a built-in type, `str` -- that wouldn't suffice, because `__hash__` is **also** crucial **and** by the time you want to do your intersection it's already been applied, putting the sets' items in different hash buckets from where they'd need to end up to make intersection work the way you want (i.e., no guarantee that 'Today' and 'today' are in the same bucket).

So, for your purposes, you inevitably need to build new data structures -- if you consider it "inelegant" to have to do that at all, you're plain out of luck: built-in sets just don't carry around the HUGE baggage and overhead that would be needed to allow people to change comparison and hashing functions, which would bloat things by 10 times (or more) for the sae of a need felt in (maybe) one use case in a million.

If you have frequent needs connected with case-insensitive comparison, you should consider subclassing or wrapping `str` (overriding comparison and hashing) to provide a "case insensitive str" type `cistr` -- and then, of course, make sure than only instances of `cistr` are (e.g.) added to your sets (&c) of interest (either by subclassing `set` &c, or simply by paying care).  To give an oversimplified example...:

```
class ci(str):
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.lower())
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.lower() == other.lower()

class cifrozenset(frozenset):
  def __new__(cls, seq=()):
    return frozenset((ci(x) for x in seq))

a = cifrozenset(('Today','I','am','fine'))
b = cifrozenset(('hello','how','are','you','today'))

print a.intersection(b)
```

this does emit `frozenset(['Today'])`, as per your expressed desire.  Of course, in real life you'd probably want to do MUCH more overriding (for example...: the way I have things here, any operation on a `cifrozenset` returns a plain `frozenset`, losing the precious case independence special feature -- you'd probably want to ensure that a `cifrozenset` is returned each time instead, and, while quite feasible, that's NOT trivial).

Comment: I guess that caching self.lower() could be an interesting first optimization?

Comment: For the problem as given (wrapping the building and intersection into a function, using return instead of print) the code I give takes 30 usec, with caching of self.lower() 44 usec. Caching the hash as well, 49 usec. Longer (3x) strings appear to behave similarly (i.e., no caching seems to work best). Accessing the cached values is a tad slower than recomputing them on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't you mean `a.intersection(b)`? The intersection (if case insensitive) would be `set(['today'])`. The difference would be `set(['i', 'am', 'fine'])`

Here are two ideas:

1.) Write a function to convert the elements of both sets to lowercase and then do the intersection. Here's one way you could do it:

```
>>> intersect_with_key = lambda s1, s2, key=lambda i: i: set(map(key, s1)).intersection(map(key, s2))
>>> fs1 = frozenset('Today I am fine'.split())
>>> fs2 = frozenset('Hello how are you TODAY'.split())
>>> intersect_with_key(fs1, fs2)
set([])
>>> intersect_with_key(fs1, fs2, key=str.lower)
set(['today'])
>>>
```

This is not very efficient though because the conversion and new sets would have to be created on each call.

2.) Extend the `frozenset` class to keep a case insensitive copy of the elements. Override the `intersection` method to use the case insensitive copy of the elements. This would be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, meant intersection ... doh.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a_, b_ = map(set, [map(str.lower, a), map(str.lower, b)])
>>> a_ & b_
set(['today'])
```

Or... with less maps,

```
>>> a_ = set(map(str.lower, a))
>>> b_ = set(map(str.lower, b))
>>> a_ & b_
set(['today'])
```